# How to convert string to expression ( value ) in aurelia repeat for?

Tags: javascript, aurelia, aurelia-templating

**Array used in repeat for loop**

```
let loopArr = ["item.name + ' /'+ item.DisplayName? item.DisplayName: item.otherDisplayName", 
                    "item.description + ' /'+ item.anotherDescription"]
```

**Template**

```
<div repeat.for = item of data">
    <div repeat.for = "row of loopArr">
        <span textcontent.bind="renderRow(row, item)></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Component method**

```
renderRow(row, item){
    return eval(row)
}
```

**Actually I wanted to display like below in template**

```
<div repeat.for = item of data">
    <div repeat.for = "row of loopArr">
        <span>${item.name + ' /'+ item.DisplayName? item.DisplayName: item.otherDisplayName} </span>
        <span>${item.description + ' /'+ item.anotherDescription} </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since I wanted to loop through **dynamic loopArr**, instead of using eval to convert from string to value, is there any better way to compute the value from string? Also, eval doesnt work for multiline statements, is there any other approach/way to handle the above problem?

How to convert string to value and display in aurelia template?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: your question is unclear (at least to me). Could you give us an example dataset you are using and the html result you want to achieve after rendering? a https://gist.dumber.app/ starting point would be nice as well, we can work towards the solution from that starting point

Comment: thanks for the response, I got the solution now, next time i'll add a working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're adding the logic in string format and using `eval`. You could directly add it to the `template` and display it:

```html
<div repeat.for="item of data">
  <span>${item.name + '/' + (item.DisplayName ? item.DisplayName: item.otherDisplayName)}</span>
  <span>${item.description + ' / '+ item.anotherDescription} </span>
</div>
```

---

Let's assume you have a list of custom string formats and you are importing them from another file. You could create an **array of functions** instead of array of strings. This is much better way of deferring the string creation than running `eval`

```js
displayTemplates = [
 item => item.name + '/' + (item.DisplayName ? item.DisplayName: item.otherDisplayName),
 item => item.description + '/'+ item.anotherDescription
]
```

and then in the `template`:

```html
<div repeat.for="item of data">
  <template repeat.for="func of displayTemplates">
      <span>${ func(item) }</span> <!-- call each func on item object -->
    </template>
</div>
```

---

Also, there is a logical error in your string format. `+` operator has [higher precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) compared to the ternary operator.

So,

```js
item.name + '/' + item.DisplayName ? item.DisplayName : item.otherDisplayName
```

is actually evaluated as

```js
(item.name + '/' + item.DisplayName) ? item.DisplayName : item.otherDisplayName
```

So, this expression will always evaluate to `item.DisplayName` because `item.name + '/' + item.DisplayName` will never be [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

You need to add `()` around the ternary operation:

```js
item.name + '/' + (item.DisplayName ? item.DisplayName: item.otherDisplayName)
// OR
item.name + '/' + (item.DisplayName ?? item.otherDisplayName)
```